# RestKit mapping issue. Same Keypaths, different path patterns & request methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapping, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm having a problem with RestKit.

I configure `responseDescriptors` to map **POST** requests to `/users/login` with `generalResponseMapping` and **GET** requests to `/users/:userID` with `userMapping`.

Init code:

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseURL];

    ...

RKObjectMapping *generalResponseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];
[generalResponseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"status", @"token" ]];

RKEntityMapping *userMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
userMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"userID" ];
[userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"avatar", @"name", @"email" ]];


void(^configureResponse)(RKMapping *,        RKRequestMethod,        NSString *,        NSString *,        NSIndexSet *) =
                       ^(RKMapping *mapping, RKRequestMethod method, NSString *pattern, NSString *keyPath, NSIndexSet *statusCodes)
{
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
                                                                                            method:method
                                                                                       pathPattern:pattern
                                                                                           keyPath:keyPath
                                                                                       statusCodes:statusCodes];
    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
};

NSIndexSet *codes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);

configureResponse(generalResponseMapping, RKRequestMethodPOST, @"users/login",   nil, codes);   
configureResponse(userMapping,            RKRequestMethodGET,  @"users/:userID", nil, codes);

    ...
```

But when I try to send a **POST** request to `/users/login`.

```
- (void)loginWithUserdata:(NSDictionary *)userdata
{   
    NSString *path = @"users/login";

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    [objectManager postObject:nil
                         path:path
                   parameters:userdata
                      success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
 {
    ...
 }
                      failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
    ...
 }];
}
```

I get error because RestKit is trying to map my `generalResponse` object with `userMapping`

```
restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:231 Asked to map source object {
    status = 0;
    token = "some_fake_token";
} with mapping <RKEntityMapping:0x9bb9040 objectClass=User propertyMappings=(
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x9bc5980 avatar => avatar>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x9b64dc0 name => name>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x9bc5700 email => email>",
    "<RKAttributeMapping: 0x9bc6a20 id => userID>",
)>
```

How can I map responses from both paths with appropriate mappings without rearranging objectManagers responseDescriptors before every request?

#### UPD

Log of RestKit network module:

```
restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:178 POST 'http://api.myapp.com/users/login':
request.headers={
Accept = "application/json";
"Accept-Language" = "en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, zh-Hans;q=0.7, zh-Hant;q=0.6, ja;q=0.5";
"Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
"User-Agent" = "MyApp/666 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 7.0; Scale/2.00)";
}
request.body=email=t&password=t
```

If I comment out addition of responseDescriptor for `users/:userID` I can successfully get right mapping and Network module will log:

```
restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:248 POST 'http://api.myapp.com/users/login' (200 OK / 1 objects) [request=0.0286s mapping=7.6855s total=7.7190s]:
response.headers={
"Cache-Control" = "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Mon, 07 Oct 2013 23:18:06 GMT";
Etag = "\"555dbdf216a0f30229810af9411ad7c9\"";
"Keep-Alive" = "timeout=20";
Server = nginx;
Status = "200 OK";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
"X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
"X-Request-Id" = "07803850-cfe3-4ccb-9a0d-46be980b0537";
"X-Runtime" = "0.004017";
"X-UA-Compatible" = "chrome=1";
"X-XSS-Protection" = "1; mode=block";
}
response.body={"status":0,"token":"some_fake_token"}
```

Otherwise I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the end of @autoreleasepool block in `-[RKMapperOperation mapSourceRepresentationWithMappingsDictionary]` and Network block logging stays quiet.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure as the request type should provide the split required. This line:

```
NSString *path = @"/users/login";
```

Change to:

```
NSString *path = @"users/login";
```

Adding slashes to one part of the path pattern and not another (on the response descriptors) can cause failures when RestKit tries to match them.

Comment: No effect. Updated question according to your proposal.

Comment: Are you getting a redirect or something? Have you debugged what is actually hitting the wire and being received back (particularly the headers)?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. Updated question with RestKit Network module logging part.

Comment: `RKResponseDescriptor` has a number of 'matches...' Methods, I'd look at debugging those to see what happens. The 2 patterns should both match but the method type should distinguish the descriptors.